# Deploying MVC4 application to Windows Server 2003 and IIS 7 (error 0x8007000d)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-7

I have had always problems deploying MVC 4 web applications in any platform, getting it working after a lot of hours. However, at this time, I have found other new problem with an installation in Windows Server.

The error I am getting is that web.config file is not a well formed XML document. Microsoft pages, as usual, does not provide real solutions to the problems with its software. It only shows that I have not a well formed XML document, what is not true. That web.config is the same file I use in my development machine.

I installed the application in a folder named C:\Folder\Website, which has read permissions for user IUSR.

I have ran "aspnet_regiis -i" command

I have used local Administrator account for the application pool

I have used iisreset

Nothing helps

Can you help me to resolve this issue, please?

Regards,
Jaime

EDIT:

By using IIS 7 management console, and trying to change some configuration, the same error occurs, mentioning that the problem is at line 3 of web.config.

This is the start of web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación de ASP.NET, visite
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Comment: This is a nonsense. I have removed the comments and web application worked. Anyone has the explanation to this?  I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to grant IUSR both read and write privileges.  Try that?